# MySQL function returning error

Tags: mysql

`#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION Test.FnGetLastDayLastFinYear (pdate datetime)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

Declare MonthNo int;
Declare YearNo int;

DECLARE OUTPUTDATE DATETIME;    

SELECT MonthNo = DATEPART(MONTH,@pdate);

if(@MonthNo <= 3)
then

        SELECT @YearNo = (DatePart(Year,getdate()) - 1);


        Select @OUTPUTDATE = Date_Format(@YearNo,'%d/%m/%Y');


ELSE

        Select  @OUTPUTDATE= Date_Format(@pdate,'%d/%m/%Y');
END If;

RETURN @OUTPUTDATE;
END
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Just posting a bunch of code and not really asking a question isn't helpful... what is your question?

Comment: I m really sry for that....i am getting this error while generating this user function....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "return" a result set, then you must use `CREATE PROCEDURE` and not `CREATE FUNCTION`

in the [docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) it is explained that you can use `CREATE FUNCTION` only when you return a single value.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to set the variable in your `FUNCTION` and return it, then I would suggest using

```
SELECT field INTO your-variable FROM rest-of-normal-select;
```

e.g.

```
Declare MonthNo int;
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,pdate) INTO MonthNo;
```

This works only if `DATEPART` itself is a `FUNCTION` that works as expected.

Comment: Clearly, he wants to return a single value from a function...?

Comment: I want to return single value from function

Comment: I added my suggestion of how i would do it. I am not familiar with your approach of assignment. I use ```SELECT INTO``` and that works fine in my database.